# How to get file name from ElementUI "el-upload" in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I would like to get the uploaded file name so I can use it in the :action URL for the POST request. I am assuming this needs to occur during :before-upload or can it be retrieved without the method?

Documentation reference: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload#upload

```html
<el-upload
  class="upload-demo"
  drag
  :action="url+filename+query"
  :on-error="handleUploadError"
  :on-success="handleUploadSuccess"
  :auto-upload="false"
  :before-upload="handleUploadbefore"
  :file-list="fileList"
  multiple>
  <i class="el-icon-upload"></i>
  <div class="el-upload__text">Drop file here or <em>click to upload</em></div>
  <div class="el-upload__tip" slot="tip">Only files with a size less than 3MB.</div>
</el-upload>
```

The target URL for file upload is basically url+filename+query.

```js
import { baseURL } from "@/utils/constants";

export default {
  name: "upload",
  data() {
    return {
      url: `${baseURL}/files/`,
      filename: null,
      query: `?override=true&auth=`
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleUploadBefore() {

      return true;
    },    
    handleUploadError() {
      console.log("File upload failed.");
    },
    handleUploadSuccess() {
      console.log("File upload succeeded!");
    },
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature of `before-upload` is `function(file) {}`, where `file` is a `File` object, which provides a [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name) prop.

The solution is to update your callback to receive the `file` parameter:

```js
handleUploadBefore(file) {
  console.log(file.name)
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/PoZWGoG)

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with out using the `before-upload` via `$refs`

`this.$refs.upload.uploadFiles[0].name`

[demo](https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/OJMpaWq?editors=1111)